# YII2 location of protected and components folders

Tags: yii2

Yii2 installed via composer with agreement official guide. But there is no 'protected' folder in the root of project.  In guides, how to work with 'components' where is always protected/components folders. Where can I find it. My project have a bit different structure, that showed in guides.

Comment: May be you were following **yii1 guide**, Yii2 don't have protected folder, components directory is created in app itself, if not then you can manually create it. [See Yii2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html)